# Android changing color of search icon

Tags: android

I have a toolbar with a menu, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:title="Map"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

This is ic_search:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
</vector>
```

Which is white.

Now when I load this menu on my activity the icon shows up as dark! the map icon shows as white though. How is this possible?

toolbar.xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post your styles.xml, you probably should be using LightActionBar

Comment: post your toolbar xml code and style you are using in it

Comment: just did. found out its happening to other icons as well -- i create a vector drawable with android studio, then change the color, it is never reflected in the app!

Answer (score 0):

change the `android:tint` property